# Overlay wont cover dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Question Background:**

I have a MVC app who's data is rendered through jQuery then appended to an empty div within the apps View. An Overlay is attached to a div that contains these elements and should cover all of the View.

**The Issue:**

I can add an Overlay and it is rendering within the view but the elements generated through jQuery are not covered, **they're place on top of the overlay, as shown, rather than underneath the Overlay**:

[image]

As can be seen the overlay is being rendered (denoted by the grey colour) but the elements are on top of it.

**The Code:**

*Overlay styling:*

```
.overlay{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*dim the background*/
}
```

*The Overlay container where which the items are appended to:*

```
<div id="myNav">
        <div id="containerId" class="container">
            <div class="topOffSet">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div id="itemHolder">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <ul id="pagination-demo"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*jQuery used to append Model Item to the above `ItemContainer` div:*

```
           for(var g = 0; g < arrayLength; g++)
            {
                var urlImage = '@Url.Content("~/Images/")';

                var fullSourceImg = urlImage + pageItems[g].img;

                htmlToAdd += '<div class="col-lg-4">'+
                                '<div class="panel panel-default maxPanelHeight">'+
                                    '<div class="panel-heading textOverflow" id="panelHeading">'+
                                        '<h3 class="panel-title text-center"><b>'+pageItems[g].Title+'</b></h3>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="panel-body">'+
                                        '<a href="'+pageItems[g].url+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+pageItems[g].Image+'" class="picHeight img-rounded img-responsive center-block" /></a>'+
                                        '<h4 class="text-center"><b>'+pageItems[g].Price+'</b></h4>'+
                                        '<h4 class="text-center"><a href="'+pageItems[g].url+'" class="btn btn-success" target="_blank">See More</a></h4>'+
                                        '<div class="text-center"><img class="originPic" src="'+fullSourceImg+'" /></div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'
            }

            $('#itemHolder').append(htmlToAdd);
```

*Code used to add the Overlay class to myNav:*

```
 document.getElementById('myNav').className = 'overlay';
```

Comment: Your 'itemHolder' is a child of the 'myNav'.  Why wouldn't it be on top of the nav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work if you just change the styling of the container element. It's children will always be on top of it, as Taplar states. What you should do is create another element that serves as the overlay, prepend it to the container, give it an absolute positioning, width and height of 100% and a high enough z-index. That will create an overlay over the element, and thus over the child elements you dynamically added.

Answer (score 1):

Try this **CSS**:

```
.overlay{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*dim the background*/
}

.overlay .container,
.overlay .itemHolder  /*Just added temporary, you cna remove this */
{
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, you want the products to be covered by the overlay.

In this case, you will need to create a separate element, instead of just adding a class to the element that contains the products.

Something like this:

```
<div id="myNav">
   ...
</div>

<div id="overlay">
   ...
</div>
```

Then in your CSS, use `#overlay` and set it to `display: none;` by default, and when you want to show it:

```
document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that your generated elements are children of the `<div id="myNav">`. The children will always have the same z-index as your `<div id="myNav">`.

You have to put a `<div>` next to `<div id="myNav">` on the same hierarchical level with a higher z-index than your `div` for your generated elements. I changed your code below to achieve this.

HTML:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <ul id="pagination-demo"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*dim the background*/
 }
 #myNav{
    /*your styles*/
    z-index:1;
 }
```

Everytime you want to fade the overlay in or out , you can use jQuery:

jQuery:

```
$(".overlay").fadeIn(500) //500 means 500ms = 0.5 seconds
$(".overlay").fadeOut(500)
```

If you want to display something on top of your overlay, just add children to the `<div class="overlay">`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the text. I have done things like this before and the styles are not applied to the generated elements. A solution would be to create an element like:

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.className = 'col-lg-4';
elem.innerHTML = '' + yourText;
container.appendChild(elem);
```

If this doesn't work for you, tell me and I will try to search a htmlparser script.

EDIT: You can even try to `innerHTML` and not `appendChild` the text.